# Nesting 2 ListViewBuilder in a SingleScrollView let the app freezing

Tags: flutter

I need 2 different lists in a scrollable view, so i did the following:

```
body:SingleChildScrollView(
    physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
                          ListView.builder(
                            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemBuilder: (context,index){
                            return Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              height: 75,
                              child: Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                 
                                  
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                         ),

                          ListView.builder(
                            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemBuilder: (context,index){
                            return Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              height: 75,
                              child: Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                 
                                  
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                         ),
  
      ]
      ),
  ),
```

If i press the button to open this ListView nothing happens and the app is frezzed.
Any idea ?
Let me know if you need more information,
Thanks

Comment: use `CustomScrollView` and its `slivers:` property, the docs say: *"A ScrollView that creates custom scroll effects using slivers.

A CustomScrollView lets you supply slivers directly to create various scrolling effects, such as lists, grids, and expanding headers. For example, to create a scroll view that contains an expanding app bar followed by a list and a grid, use a list of three slivers: SliverAppBar, SliverList, and SliverGrid."*

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn`t work either. Can you give me an code example? thank you

Comment: `CustomScrollView(slivers: [SliverList(delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(...)), SliverList(delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(...))]);`